# Border Radius property on Css 2

Tags: html, css

I want to make a div using border-radius property and send it to an Email Provider like Outlook, Gmail, Yahoo etc. The problem is these clients dont support CSS 3 (border-radius) property.
Is there a way to use a property border-radius in CSS 2.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know if it's a button you need, but the principle is the same.

You can create a VML button with [buttons.cm](http://buttons.cm/) this will work everywhere including Outlook however it has to be fixed width. You can then make it 100% wide with a media query.

A downside with the VML button is that it creates 2 versions of the button, and both will appear when the email is forwarded by a subscriber using the email client's native forwarding functionality.